# Strange class cast happening

Tags: c++, class, casting

I received a code to review and I can't understand why a class cast is happening. Given the following dummy code:

```
class A {

    int a;
    void dummy() {
        std::cout << "wewe";
    };
};

class B {

    int a;
    void dummy() {
        std::cout << "wewe";
    };
};


A strangeCast() {
    return B();
}
```

It builds with no errors on this project on VSCode on Linux.

I checked for any relationship between the two classes: no ereditariety, no overloading of the equal operator, no cast defined.

While if I try to do it in a Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows, it tells me that class conversion is not defined (like I expect to).

Do you think I overlooked any of the above relationship or any other way for this to happen exists?

Edit: I know that is not a good code, that it has errors, but since it sounded so strange to me that it compiled without errors/warnings, I was just wondering if there was something I didn't know about.

Comment: `strangeCast()` is declared to return an `A` yet it returns a `B` (which is *not* an `A`). This seems completely broken. You cannot be showing us your actual code here.

Comment: You are not compiling the code you think you are.

Comment: There is no way the code as shown can compile. There would have to be another `B` in scope that actually derives from `A`

Comment: Even after adding `#include <iostream>` that code does not compile: https://repl.it/repls/MedicalAbandonedGoals, and there's no way it could ever compile.

Comment: I know that code will never compile. It was just to show that the two involved classes are identical except for the name. As I wrote either I overlooked one of the relationships or if some mechanisms exist that I don't know about.

Comment: @Mdp11 *It builds with no errors on this project on VSCode on Linux.* ???

Comment: @ruohola "It builds with no errors" means *next to nothing*. Lots of invalid code with Undefined Behaviour or race conditions *compiles*. That doesn't mean the code is free from errors or in any way *valid*. "It compiles" is a *Very low* bar.

Comment: @ruohola I meant that using the same compiler (g++) on both systems

Comment: @Mdp11 why do you have 2 identical classes except the name? That's either bad design, or there's something else you're not explaining properly.

Answer (score 2):

> Strange class cast happening

There is no cast whatsoever. Cast is an **explicit** conversion. What you're showing is an implicit conversion.

> or any other way for this to happen exists?

The program is ill-formed. Only possibility for this to compile is a language extension of the compiler that you are using. Regardless, if there is no diagnostic message, then the compiler does not conform to the standard.